# how to get multiple inputs in one line in C#

Tags: c#, .net, input

How can I  input multiple integers or strings in one line?

For example, int p would take values:
1 2 3 4 5 6

**but now I know the answer to my own question i.e:**

```
var p= Console.ReadLine().split(' ');
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Can you provide an example of what you've tried and how it isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014292/concatenate-integers-in-c-sharp)

Comment: well, I now know how to input multiple values in one line so plz open the question again because it is now clear what I asked and I have myself given the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can read line with numbers or srings separated with spaces (or other symbols). Then you can split the line into parts and parse values.

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();
var data = line.Split(' ');
var i1 = int.Parse(data[0]); //first integer
var i2 = int.Parse(data[1]); //second integer
```

Comment: don't you mean `data[0]` and `data[1]` ?

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to accept the single line and then split them up based on how you want the inputs separate. For example, if you make the users type in:

```
1,2,3
```

then you need to split around the comma and convert the input to numbers:

```
foreach (var sn in inp.Split(',')) {
    var n = Convert.ToInt32(sn);
    // work with n
}
```

Comment: you can also use int.TryParse if you are not sure of values passed