# How to append a "1" bit to the front of a binary integer in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

At the current moment I am trying to figure out a way to append a "1" bit to the front of a binary 32 bit integer, but only in front of the active bits. For example, "101" would turn into "1101", and 000 000 would turn into "1 000 000". Each binary integer would essentially be turned into triplets.

The reason I am wanting to do this is to implement a Hashed Octree with Morton encoding. I am mainly attempting to follow this article here: https://geidav.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/advanced-octrees-2-node-representations/

In this article, it references adding a flag "1" bit to the front of Morton code with its children in order to distinguish its location code from other location codes.

My Current Code is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Collections;

using static Unity.Mathematics.math;

using Unity.Mathematics;

public struct Octree 
{
    NativeHashMap<int, OctreeNode> octreeNodes;

    OctreeNode GetParentNode(OctreeNode node)
    {
        int locCodeParent = node.LocCode >> 3;
        return LookupNode(locCodeParent);
    }

    OctreeNode LookupNode(int LocCode)
    {
        OctreeNode node;

        if(!octreeNodes.TryGetValue(LocCode, out node))
        {
            Debug.Log("You done oofed dude, the octree node could not be found with the LocCode provided, please try again or stay oofed");
        }

        return node;
    }

    int GetNodeTreeDepth(OctreeNode node)         
    {
        return (int)log2(node.LocCode)/3;
    }
}

public struct OctreeNode
{
    public int LocCode;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014292/concatenate-integers-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you write code that identifies the bit number of the highest bit set in an integer? I

Comment: I think that I have though of a solution, will get working on it ASAP. Will update code and question once I hit the next hurdle (since it probably wont work knowing my thinking skills)

Comment: In the `000 000` example, how do you know it isn't `0 000` and should turn `10 000`: How do you tell *active* bits from *non active*?

Comment: `log2` does floating-point math to get actual logarithm value so it's extremely slow. Use [`BitOperations.Log2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.log2?view=netcore-3.0) instead which maps to a single instruction that gets the highest bit position. Alternatively use [BitOperations.TrailingZeroCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.trailingzerocount?view=netcore-3.0). [Fast way of finding most and least significant bit set in a 64-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31374628/995714)

Comment: [What's the quickest way to compute log2 of an integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8970101/995714), [Fastest implementation of log2(int) and log2(float)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15967240/995714)

Answer (score 0):

The `LongFlags` class below will maintain a (64-bit) set of `ulong` bit flags, as an abstraction. You can query the bits that are set, including querying the highest-set bit.

Your code does not show specifics; but you seem to want to be able to add a bit before another *already set* bit:

> "101" would turn into "1101"

and also a not-set bit:

> 000 000 would turn into "1 000 000"

Perhaps you would keep track of an `int` value of your highest "Current" bit; and then use this class to set the next bit ... You can set and clear any individual bits.

For example, you could wrap the below `LongFlags` in a helper like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper for bit flags, that tracks a <see cref="CurrentBit"/>.
    /// The <see cref="BitLimit"/> is limited to sixty-four.
    /// Bit positions are numbered from one to sixty-four,
    /// right-to-left (lsb is one, msb is 64).
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    public class BitHelper
    {
        [DataMember]
        private LongFlags longFlags = new LongFlags();


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bitLimit">Required: sets <see cref="BitLimit"/>.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
        public BitHelper(int bitLimit)
        {
            if ((bitLimit < 1)
                    || (bitLimit > 64))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bitLimit), bitLimit, @"[1, 64]");
            BitLimit = bitLimit;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Limits the highest bit that can be set. [1, 64].
        /// (Bit positions are numbered from one to a maximum of sixty-four,
        /// right-to-left (lsb is one, msb is 64).)
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public int BitLimit { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the current working bit position.
        /// Defaults to one. Ranges: [1, BitLimit].
        /// (Bit positions are numbered from one to a maximum of sixty-four,
        /// right-to-left (lsb is one, msb is 64).)
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public int CurrentBit { get; private set; } = 1;


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the state of the <see cref="CurrentBit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True if one, false if zero.</returns>
        public bool IsCurrentBitSet
            => longFlags[CurrentBit];

        /// <summary>
        /// Increments the <see cref="CurrentBit"/>,
        /// making no changes to bit values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">If the <see cref="CurrentBit"/>
        /// is already at the <see cref="BitLimit"/>.</exception>
        public BitHelper IncrementCurrentBit()
        {
            if (CurrentBit >= BitLimit)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(BitLimit.ToString());
            ++CurrentBit;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the <see cref="CurrentBit"/> to one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        public BitHelper SetCurrentBit()
        {
            longFlags.Set(CurrentBit);
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the <see cref="CurrentBit"/> to zero.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        public BitHelper ClearCurrentBit()
        {
            longFlags.Clear(CurrentBit);
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inverts the value of the <see cref="CurrentBit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        public BitHelper InvertCurrentBit()
        {
            longFlags[CurrentBit] = !longFlags[CurrentBit];
            return this;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the position of the highest bit that is set:
        /// [0, BitLimit]. Returns zero if no bits are set.
        /// </summary>
        public int HighestSetBit
            => longFlags.HighestFlag;


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all 64 bits as a ULong.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>All 64 bits, unsigned.</returns>
        public ulong ToULong()
            => longFlags.Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all 64 bits as a Long.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>All 64 bits, signed.</returns>
        public long ToLong()
            => (long)longFlags.Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the lower 32 bits as a UInt
        /// --- REGARDLESS of the setting of <see cref="BitLimit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The lower 32 bits, unsigned.</returns>
        public uint ToUInt()
            => (uint)longFlags.Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the lower 32 bits as an Int
        /// --- REGARDLESS of the setting of <see cref="BitLimit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The lower 32 bits, signed.</returns>
        public int ToInt()
            => (int)longFlags.Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the lower 16 bits as a UShort
        /// --- REGARDLESS of the setting of <see cref="BitLimit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The lower 16 bits, unsigned.</returns>
        public ushort ToUShort()
            => (ushort)longFlags.Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the lower 16 bits as a short
        /// --- REGARDLESS of the setting of <see cref="BitLimit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The lower 16 bits, signed.</returns>
        public short ToShort()
            => (short)longFlags.Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the lower 8 bits as a Byte
        /// --- REGARDLESS of the setting of <see cref="BitLimit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The lower 8 bits, unsigned.</returns>
        public byte ToByte()
            => (byte)longFlags.Flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the lower 8 bits as an SByte
        /// --- REGARDLESS of the setting of <see cref="BitLimit"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The lower 8 bits, signed.</returns>
        public sbyte ToSByte()
            => (sbyte)longFlags.Flags;
    }
```

Here is `LongFlags`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace Sc.Util.System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class holding <see langword="ulong"/> bit <see cref="Flags"/>.
    /// Flags are numbered from one to sixty-four, from right-to-left in the
    /// <see langword="ulong"/> value --- but the abstraction allows you to
    /// ignore that as an implementation detail. This class implements
    /// methods to set and clear flags, and set and clear flags from other
    /// instances. This also implements implicit conversions to and from
    /// <see langword="ulong"/> --- and therefore you may invoke methods with
    /// <see langword="ulong"/> values. This is also
    /// <see cref="IXmlSerializable"/> and <see cref="ICloneable"/>.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class LongFlags
            : ICloneable,
                    IXmlSerializable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Counts the bits that are set on the argument.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <returns>A count of bits that are set.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static int CountBits(ulong flags)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
                if ((flags & 1) == 1)
                    ++result;
                flags >>= 1;
            }
            return result;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the <see langword="ulong"/> VALUE of the SINGLE
        /// highest bit that is set on the argument.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <returns>The value of the single highest bit that is set.
        /// Returns zero if no bits are set.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static ulong GetHighestBitValue(ulong flags)
        {
            int highestBit = LongFlags.GetHighestBitPosition(flags);
            return highestBit == 0
                    ? 0UL
                    : 1UL << (highestBit - 1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the <see langword="ulong"/> VALUE of the SINGLE
        /// lowest bit that is set on the argument.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <returns>The value of the single lowest bit that is set.
        /// Returns zero if no bits are set.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static ulong GetLowestBitValue(ulong flags)
        {
            int lowestBit = LongFlags.GetLowestBitPosition(flags);
            return lowestBit == 0
                    ? 0UL
                    : 1UL << (lowestBit - 1);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the position of highest bit that is set on the argument:
        /// where the right-most bit is position one; and the left-most is sixty-four.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <returns>The position of the highest bit that is set.
        /// Returns zero if no bits are set.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static int GetHighestBitPosition(ulong flags)
        {
            if (flags == 0UL)
                return 0;
            for (int i = 63; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (((flags >> i) & 1) == 1)
                    return i + 1;
            }
            Debug.Fail($"Value is '{flags}' but iteration failed to find a set bit.");
            return 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the position of lowest bit that is set on the argument:
        /// where the right-most bit is position one; and the left-most is sixty-four.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <returns>The position of the lowest bit that is set.
        /// Returns zero if no bits are set.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static int GetLowestBitPosition(ulong flags)
        {
            if (flags == 0UL)
                return 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
                if (((flags >> i) & 1) == 1)
                    return i + 1;
            }
            Debug.Fail($"Value is '{flags}' but iteration failed to find a set bit.");
            return 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a new value from the <paramref name="flags"/>
        /// with the <paramref name="predicate"/> removed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <param name="predicate">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns <paramref name="flags"/> <c>&</c> the
        /// complement of the <paramref name="predicate"/>.</returns>
        public static ulong Excluding(ulong flags, ulong predicate)
            => flags & ~predicate;


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the <paramref name="source"/> has ANY of the bits that
        /// are set on the <paramref name="flags"/>. Notice that if the
        /// <paramref name="flags"/> are zero, this will return false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source flags.
        /// If zero, this will return false.</param>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary bits to search for.
        /// If zero, this will return false.</param>
        /// <returns>True if ANY <The name="flags"/> are present on the
        /// <paramref name="source"/> (and at least one flags bit is set).</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static bool HasAnyBits(ulong source, ulong flags)
            => (source & flags) != 0UL;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the <paramref name="source"/> has ALL of the bits that
        /// are set on the <paramref name="flags"/>. Notice that if the
        /// <paramref name="flags"/> are zero, this will return false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source flags.
        /// If zero, this will return false.</param>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary bits to search for.
        /// If zero, this will return false.</param>
        /// <returns>True if ALL <The name="flags"/> are present on the
        /// <paramref name="source"/> (and at least one flags bit is set).</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static bool HasAllBits(ulong source, ulong flags)
            => (flags != 0UL) && ((source & flags) == flags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the <paramref name="source"/> has ONLY bits that are set
        /// on the <paramref name="flags"/> --- false if any bit is set on the source
        /// that is not defined on the flags. Notice that if the
        /// <paramref name="flags"/> are zero, this will return false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source flags.
        /// If zero, this will return false.</param>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary bits to search for.
        /// If zero, this will return false.</param>
        /// <param name="requiresAll">If true, then <paramref name="source"/>
        /// MUST contain ALL <paramref name="flags"/> AND NO other bits.
        /// If false, the source may contain zero or more bits
        /// present on the flags --- and no bits that are not present on the flags
        /// (source need not contain all, but can only contain a bit on the flags).</param>
        /// <returns>True if only the flags are present on the source --- false if any bit is
        /// set on th source that is not defined on the flags.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static bool HasOnlyBits(ulong source, ulong flags, bool requiresAll)
            => (flags != 0UL)
                    && (source != 0UL)
                    && ((source & ~flags) == 0UL)
                    && (!requiresAll
                    || ((source & flags) == flags));

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the <paramref name="source"/> has NONE of the
        /// bits that are set on <paramref name="flags"/>. Notice that if the
        /// <paramref name="flags"/> are zero, this will return TRUE.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source flags.
        /// If zero, this will return true.</param>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary flags to search for.
        /// If zero, this will return true.</param>
        /// <returns>True if no flags bits are set here.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static bool HasNoBits(ulong source, ulong flags)
            => (source & flags) == 0UL;


        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the range.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position">[1,64].</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static void rangeCheckPosition(int position)
        {
            if ((position <= 0)
                    || (position > 64))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(position), position, @"[1,64]");
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor creates an empty instance.
        /// </summary>
        public LongFlags() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance with each flag position in the argument array set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">The flags to set.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
        public LongFlags(params int[] flags)
            => Set(flags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance with the given bits set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">The bits to copy. This directly
        /// sets <see cref="Flags"/>.</param>
        public LongFlags(ulong flags)
            => Flags = flags;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a deep clone of the argument.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clone">The value to copy.</param>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private LongFlags(LongFlags clone)
            => Flags = clone.Flags;


        XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
            => null;

        void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
            => writer.WriteString(Flags.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                Flags = 0UL;
            else {
                reader.Read();
                switch (reader.NodeType) {
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement :
                        Flags = 0UL; // empty after all...
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text :
                    case XmlNodeType.CDATA :
                        Flags = ulong.Parse(reader.ReadContentAsString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        break;
                    default :
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected text/cdata");
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The current bit flags. Flags are numbered from one to sixty-four: where
        /// the right-most bit is one, and the left-most is sixty four.
        /// Methods do not require knowledge of the flag positions; and flags
        /// are simply numbered [1,64].
        /// </summary>
        public ulong Flags
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get;
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            private set;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// An indexer that gets or sets a boolean indicating if the flag at the
        /// given <paramref name="position"/> is set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position">[1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>True if the flag is set.</returns>
        public bool this[int position]
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => IsSet(position);
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            set {
                if (value)
                    Set(position);
                else
                    Clear(position);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the flag at the given position is set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position">The position to test: [1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>True if the flag is set.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public bool IsSet(int position)
        {
            LongFlags.rangeCheckPosition(position);
            return LongFlags.HasAnyBits(Flags, 1UL << (position - 1));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if each flag in the argument array is set.
        /// This will return FALSE if none are provided.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="positions">[1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>True if all provided flags are set. NOTICE: this will
        /// return FALSE if none are provided.</returns>
        public bool IsAllSet(params int[] positions)
        {
            if (positions.Length == 0)
                return false;
            foreach (int position in positions) {
                if (!IsSet(position))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if ANY flag in the argument array is set.
        /// This will return FALSE if none are provided.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="positions">[1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>True if ANY provided flag is set; AND if AT LEAST ONE
        /// is provided.</returns>
        public bool IsAnySet(params int[] positions)
        {
            foreach (int position in positions) {
                if (IsSet(position))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if all flags are set.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsFull
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => Flags == ulong.MaxValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if no flags are set.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsEmpty
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => Flags == 0UL;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Counts the flags that are set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A count of <see cref="Flags"/> bits that are set.</returns>
        public int Count
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => LongFlags.CountBits(Flags);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the position of highest flag that is set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The position of the highest bit that is set on <see cref="Flags"/>.</returns>
        public int HighestFlag
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => LongFlags.GetHighestBitPosition(Flags);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the position of lowest flag that is set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The position of the lowest bit that is set on <see cref="Flags"/>.</returns>
        public int LowestFlag
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => LongFlags.GetLowestBitPosition(Flags);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the <see langword="ulong"/> VALUE of the SINGLE
        /// highest bit that is set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The value of the single highest bit that is set on <see cref="Flags"/>.</returns>
        public ulong HighestFlagValue
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => LongFlags.GetHighestBitValue(Flags);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the <see langword="ulong"/> VALUE of the SINGLE
        /// lowest bit that is set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The value of the single lowest bit that is set on <see cref="Flags"/>.</returns>
        public ulong LowestFlagValue
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get => LongFlags.GetLowestBitValue(Flags);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the flag at the position specified by the argument.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position">[1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags Set(int position)
        {
            LongFlags.rangeCheckPosition(position);
            Flags |= 1UL << (position - 1);
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the flag at each specified position.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="positions">[1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags Set(params int[] positions)
        {
            ulong flags = Flags;
            try {
                foreach (int position in positions) {
                    Set(position);
                }
                return this;
            } catch {
                Flags = flags;
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets all flags to one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags SetAll()
        {
            Flags = ulong.MaxValue;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears the flag at the position specified by the argument.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position">[1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags Clear(int position)
        {
            LongFlags.rangeCheckPosition(position);
            Flags &= ~(1UL << (position - 1));
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears the flag at each position specified in the argument array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="positions">[1,64].</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags Clear(params int[] positions)
        {
            ulong flags = Flags;
            try {
                foreach (int position in positions) {
                    Clear(position);
                }
                return this;
            } catch {
                Flags = flags;
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resets all <see cref="Flags"/> to zero.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags Clear()
        {
            Flags = 0UL;
            return this;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Sets <see cref="Flags"/> to the argument's value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clone">The value to copy.</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags SetFrom(LongFlags clone)
        {
            Flags = clone.Flags;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets <see cref="Flags"/> to the argument's value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clone">The value to copy.</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags SetFrom(ulong clone)
        {
            Flags = clone;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds all of the flags in the argument to this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary flags to add.</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags AddAllFlags(LongFlags flags)
        {
            Flags |= flags.Flags;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all flags defined on the argument from this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary flags to remove.</param>
        /// <returns>This object for chaining.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags RemoveAllFlags(LongFlags flags)
        {
            Flags &= ~flags.Flags;
            return this;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this instance has ANY of the <see cref="Flags"/>
        /// defined on the argument. Notice that if the
        /// <paramref name="flags"/> are zero, this will return false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary flags to search for.</param>
        /// <returns>True if any flags are present here
        /// (and at least one flag bit is set).</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public bool HasAny(LongFlags flags)
            => LongFlags.HasAnyBits(Flags, flags.Flags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this instance has ALL of the <see cref="Flags"/>
        /// defined on the argument. Notice that if the
        /// <paramref name="flags"/> are zero, this will return false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary flags to search for.</param>
        /// <returns>True if ALL flags are present here
        /// (and at least one flag bit is set).</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public bool HasAll(LongFlags flags)
            => LongFlags.HasAllBits(Flags, flags.Flags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this instance has ONLY flags that are set
        /// on the <paramref name="flags"/> --- false if any flag is set here
        /// that is not defined on the flags. Notice that if the
        /// <paramref name="flags"/> are zero, this will return false
        /// --- and if this <see cref="Flags"/> is zero this returns false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary flags to search for.
        /// If zero, this will return false.</param>
        /// <param name="requiresAll">If true, then this
        /// MUST contain ALL <paramref name="flags"/> AND NO other flags.
        /// If false, this may contain zero or more flags
        /// present on the flags --- and no flags that are not present on the flags
        /// (this need not contain all, but can only contain a flag on the flags).</param>
        /// <returns>True if only the flags are present here --- false if any flag is
        /// set here that is not defined on the flags.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public bool HasOnly(LongFlags flags, bool requiresAll)
            => LongFlags.HasOnlyBits(Flags, flags.Flags, requiresAll);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this instance has NONE of the <see cref="Flags"/>
        /// defined on the argument.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flags">Arbitrary.</param>
        /// <returns>True if no flags are present here.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public bool HasNone(LongFlags flags)
            => LongFlags.HasNoBits(Flags, flags.Flags);


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a deep clone of this object.
        /// </summary>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public LongFlags Clone()
            => new LongFlags(this);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        object ICloneable.Clone()
            => Clone();


        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static implicit operator ulong(LongFlags longFlags)
            => longFlags.Flags;

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static implicit operator LongFlags(ulong flags)
            => new LongFlags(flags);


        public override string ToString()
            => $"{nameof(LongFlags)}"
                    + "["
                    + $"{Convert.ToString((byte)(Flags >> 56), 2)}"
                    + $" {Convert.ToString((byte)(Flags >> 48), 2)}"
                    + $" {Convert.ToString((byte)(Flags >> 40), 2)}"
                    + $" {Convert.ToString((byte)(Flags >> 32), 2)}"
                    + $" {Convert.ToString((byte)(Flags >> 24), 2)}"
                    + $" {Convert.ToString((byte)(Flags >> 16), 2)}"
                    + $" {Convert.ToString((byte)(Flags >> 8), 2)}"
                    + $" {Convert.ToString((byte)Flags, 2)}"
                    + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: why on earth do you write such a complex class with `GetHighestBitPosition` when there are already `BitOperations.Log2` and `BitOperations.TrailingZeroCount` which are intrinsics and map directly to the CPU instruction